# MySQL: SET a value only if a value in another column is unique

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

I want to `SET` a boolean value to True in one column, but only if the value in an adjacent column is unique (regardless of what that value is).

Assume `ROOM_IS_PRIVATE` is the boolean column I'm setting, and `ROOM_VALUE` is the column whose value I want to check for uniqueness. I'm fairly new to writing queries, so here's what I have so far:

```
SET ROOM_IS_PRIVATE = '1'
WHERE COUNT(ROOM_VALUE) = 1;
```

But this isn't working for me. Am I even on the right track using the count function?

**EDIT:** Here's a sample of the results I hope to achieve:

```
|  ROOM_VALUE  |  ROOM_IS_PRIVATE  |
|--------------|-------------------|
|      54      |         0         |
|      13      |         1         |
|      08      |         0         |
|      08      |         0         |
|      54      |         0         |
|      19      |         1         |
|      08      |         0         |
```

The second column only becomes `1` if the value in the first column is unique to that column.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done, sir

Comment: @TomCrews, does below answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET` clause looks right. But it's not a valid statement; looks like we're  missing the `UPDATE` keyword, the name of the table we're updating.

If we want to modify ONLY rows where `room_value` is unique, we could do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.room_value
              , COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM mytable r
          GROUP BY r.room_value
       ) s
    ON s.room_value = t.room_value 
   SET t.room_is_private = CASE WHEN s.cnt = 1 THEN 1 ELSE t.room_is_private END
```

The inline view `s` is executed and the results are materialized as a derived table. This gets us distinct values of `room_value`, along with the number of rows with the same `room_value`.

Then We join the derived tale back to the original table, matching on `room_value` column, so now, for each row in our table, we can know the count of rows that have the same `room_value`.

In the `SET` clause, we are using an expression that tests the count, and conditionally assigns a `1` (when `cnt=1`) and otherwise leaves the value of `room_is_private` unchanged.

I suspect that we probably also want to set `room_is_private` = 0 when room_value is not unique,  so rather than set `room_is_private` to the current value (i.e. leaving it unchanged), we would instead assign a `0`.

```
UPDATE mytable t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.room_value
              , COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM mytable r
          GROUP BY r.room_value
       ) s
    ON s.room_value = t.room_value 
   SET t.room_is_private = CASE WHEN s.cnt = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so well. This answer is going to help with a lot more queries I'll be writing.

Comment: @TomCrews: It's good to have an understanding of the patterns, useful tools for our SQL toolbelts, so we can employ those same patterns on other queries.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this-

```
SELECT 
    ROOM_IS_PRIVATE = CASE WHEN COUNT(ROOM_VALUE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM yourtableName
```

Comment: This query is going to return a single row... the count aggregate is going to get us a count of the number of rows with non-NULL value for `room_value` (essentially a single count of all rows in the table), then that's going to be compared to a literal 1, and then return either a 1 or a 0, then compare the 0 or 1 to an indeterminate value of `room_is_private`, evaluated that in a boolean context to return 0, 1 or NULL. This query will probably execute, but I don't see how this addresses the question asked by OP. This answer must have been upvoted by a diehard fan for "try this" answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try a conditional update like this:

```
update a set 
a.ROOM_IS_PRIVATE= case when cnt is null then 1 else 
a.ROOM_IS_PRIVATE end 
from yourtable a  
left join(
select roomvalue, count(*) cnt
from yourtable
group by roomvalue
having count(*)>1 )b
on a.roomvalue=b.roomvalue
```